# rxjs angular 2: search filter with multiple terms

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, rxjs5

I am trying to implement search with multiple terms. N [chart flow of want i tried to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu92O.png)

i read this blog: https://netbasal.com/manage-your-filters-like-a-pro-in-angular-with-combinelatest-e7b0204be2df it similar case. but i didn't understand how i can implement it with dynamic observables(search terms input). 
let say i have filter with 30 search terms. the easy solution will be to use combineLatest to all search terms components but its not efficient.
My goal is to subscribe to observables on their first change.

i tried to use the combineLatest operator with dynamic array but it didnt work:(.

my code:

```html
import {Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChildren, QueryList, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Table} from "../../models/table";
import {InputFilterComponent} from "../types/input-filter/input-filter.component";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Component({
  selector: '[phantom-thead-filter]',
  template: '<th>Actions</th>
  <th *ngFor="let col of cols" class="ng2-smart-th {{ col.title }}" [ngClass]="col?.class">
    <input-filter [col]="col" [table]="table"></input-filter>
  </th>
  ',
  styleUrls: ['./phantom-thead-filter.component.css']
})
export class PhantomTheadFilterComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() cols;
  @Input() table: Table;
  @ViewChildren(InputFilterComponent) filters : QueryList<InputFilterComponent>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const filters = this.filters.map(f => f.getFilterWatcher());
    Observable.combineLatest(filters)
      .map(( filters : any[] ) => {
        filters.map((filter) => {
          return filter;
        });
      });
  }

}




import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";
import {Table} from "../../../models/table";

@Component({
  selector: 'input-filter',
  template: '<input [formControl]="inputControl"
                    class="form-control"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="input" />',
  styleUrls: ['./input-filter.component.css']
})
export class InputFilterComponent implements OnInit {
  inputControl = new FormControl();
  @Input() col;
  @Input() table: Table;
  changeFilter: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changeFilter =this.inputControl.valueChanges
      .skip(1)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .debounceTime(400)
      .map((value: string) => {
        return value;
      }).startWith(null);
  }

  getFilterWatcher() {
    return this.changeFilter;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.changeFilter.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you give more code ? Your observable search input and combineLatest where you combine it.

Answer (score 0):

CombineLatest waits for all observables to emit their first value.

If you want to query even if you don't set all filters, you can use `startWith` to provide a virtual first null value.

```
const filters = this.filters.map(f => f.changeFilter.startWith(null));

Observable.combineLatest(...filters)
          .map(( filters : ActiveFilter[] ) => {
                // All filters are defined, but not all have values [null, 'search', null, null]
          });
```

Comment: is there way to add filters dynamic. will it be more efficient ?

also the example from the blog didnt work for me:
i updated my code.

Comment: You can have an observable of filters, that emits the list of enabled filters. Then you can combine them and connect their `changeFilter` to a api request.

Comment: why my current code didnt work?
i found this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-state-angular-2-ngrx/  is the only right way to do it or with rxjs we can achive the same result

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this approach:

```
let listObs = [];
const searchTermA = Observable.fromEvent(this.searchInputARef.nativeElement, 'keyup').debounceTime(300).distinctUntilChanged();
listObs = [...listObs, searchTermA];

const searchTermB = Observable.fromEvent(this.searchInputBRef.nativeElement, 'keyup').debounceTime(300).distinctUntilChanged();
listObs = [...listObs, searchTermB];

Observable.combineLatest(list).subscribe(latestValues => {
    const [searchTermAValue, searchTermBValue] = latestValues;
});
```